# Reading the properties of an instance of the Object Class java

Tags: java, android, xml-rpc

in my project im using the XML-RPC to get results from a web Server using the XML-RPC method `.execute` which returns an Object.

```
public List getAll(final String[] fields){
        List<Object> records = new ArrayList<>()  ;
        try {
            records = asList((Object[])this.models.execute("execute_kw", asList(
                    DB, this.uid, PASSWORD,
                    "res.partner", "search_read",
                    asList(asList(
                            /*asList("is_company", "=", true),
                            asList("customer", "=", true)*/)),
                    new HashMap() {{
                        put("fields", asList(fields));
                    }}
            )));
        } catch (XmlRpcException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return records;
    }
```

i get something like this : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI3YU.jpg)

How do i read each Object Properties ?